# Intellij and javac disagree on unchecked cast

Tags: java, intellij-idea

A simple test case:

```
    Object o = new ArrayList<String>();
    var s = (List<String>) o;
```

This code is disliked by javac on the grounds of unchecked cast. As far as I can tell, there is no command line option to get javac to shut up; the only way to do it is to add an annotation in the code itself:

```
    Object o = new ArrayList<String>();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    var s = (List<String>) o;
```

but this version is disliked by Intellij, which thinks the suppression is redundant. For most kinds of warnings, Intellij provides an interactive way to disable the warning, but not this one.

What's the best way to get the two to agree on some version of the code? The ideal would be a way to make javac happy with the first version, because I've gone with the modern idea that IDE files are not checked into version control; the Maven project definition is definitive, and IDE project definition is re-created from it if necessary; this means everyone can make their own user-specific tweaks to IDE settings, but it would be much better if project-specific tweaks to IDE settings could be avoided.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using? Using `2019.1.3` I get an "unchecked cast" warning in the IDE using your code. Adding the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation is not marked as redundant; however, it does tell me the annotation can be removed by changing the type of `o` to `List<String>`.

Comment: @Slaw I'm using 2019.1.3.

Comment: Odd. Only thing I can think to do is check what inspections are enabled and their configuration.

Comment: @Slaw That works, thanks! Ctrl-Shift-Alt-H, configure inspections, Java/compiler issues/unchecked warning, disabled by default, enable and it agrees with javac.